XForms + MQTT Websocket JS integration. (XSLTForms + Paho)
I am trying to integrate Xforms - using XSLTForms - and MQTT, over a Websocket using Paho JS library talking to a Mosquitto broker.
I have successfully managed to send a message using xf:load (albeit with a static string as my message), but I can't figure out the way to receive any inbound messages in Xforms.
I was thinking that the onMessageArrived function (see below) should probably fire a custom JS event (I don't know how to do that, and whether or not that is the right thing to do) - and I should use an xf:action block to react to that. (I don't know how to do that either - how to register against any custom events? How to receive the payload?).
The code below also confirms that the incoming MQTT message is picked-up by the javascript function - as the browser console logs the incoming messages - I just don't know how to pass that onto Xforms.
Update.
I have come up with the following solution to process the incoming messages - not sure this is the right way of doing things:
An invisible (via CSS) button:
<xf:trigger id="t_receive" style="display: none">
    <xf:label>RECEIVE MQTT MESSAGE</xf:label>
    <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
        <xf:insert
            nodeset="message"
            at="last()"
            position="after"/>
        <xf:setvalue
            ref="message[last()]"
            value="'MQTT MESSAGE RECEIVED'"/>
    </xf:action>
</xf:trigger>

And I 'click' the button from Javascript like this:
function onMessageArrived(message) {                
    console.log("onMessageArrived:"+message.payloadString);
    document.querySelector("#t_receive").click()
            
};

Update 2
Instead of 'clicking' the button, we can actually dispatch the event directly from xsltforms.js it seems. (I'm still sorta clicking here - but I guess there is probably a better event I can use, which doesn't rely on the 'invisible' trigger).
function js_dispatch() {
    var trigger=document.querySelector("#t_receive");
    XsltForms_xmlevents.dispatch(trigger, "DOMActivate");
}

function onMessageArrived(message) {
                console.log("onMessageArrived:"+message.payloadString);
                //document.querySelector("#t_receive").click()
                js_dispatch();
};


Update 3
In fact: a trigger is not needed at all - and I learnt that events can be entirely custom.
By adding an ID to model, we can use that as the event source.
(A trick I saw in this (brilliant) XForms clock example).
<xf:model id="model">
[...]
<xf:action ev:event="mqtt_connected">
            <xf:message>MQTT CONNECTED</xf:message>
</xf:action>
[...]
</xf:model>

Then dispatch the event as so:
function onConnect() {
            console.log("onConnect");
            var model=document.querySelector("#model");
            XsltForms_xmlevents.dispatch(model, "mqtt_connected");
        };

Additionally - here's a way (not particular happy with all the text concat'ing - horrible to maintain) to provide arguments for a JS function:
    <xf:instance id="config">
            <config xmlns="">
                <fn fn_name="connect">
                    <hostname>localhost</hostname>
                    <port>9001</port>
                    <clientID>browser</clientID>
                    <link/>
                </fn>
            </config>
        </xf:instance>
        <xf:bind
                ref="instance('config')/fn[@fn_name='connect']/port"
                type="integer"/>
        <xf:bind
                ref="instance('config')/fn[@fn_name='connect']/link"
                calculate="concat( 'javascript:connect(',
                                    '''',
                                    ../hostname,
                                    '''',
                                    ',',
                                    ../port,
                                    ',',
                                    '''',
                                    ../clientID,
                                    '''',
                                    ')' 
                            )"/>

Then to invoke the JS + args from a trigger:
<xf:trigger id="connectmq">
    <xf:label>CONNECT</xf:label>
        <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
            <xf:load>
               <xf:resource value="link"/>
            </xf:load>
        </xf:action>
</xf:trigger>


<?xml
    version="1.0"
    encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet
    href="/declarative4all/build/xsl/xsltforms.xsl"
    type="text/xsl"?>
<?xsltforms-options
    debug="yes"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:ht="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"   
      xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
      lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta
            charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta
                name="viewport"
                content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <title>MQTT and XForms Test</title>
        <script src="js/paho-mqtt.js">
        </script>

        <xf:model>
            <xf:instance id="messages">
                <messages xmlns="">
                    <message>Initialized</message>
                </messages>
            </xf:instance>
        </xf:model>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>MQTT and XForms Test</h1>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var hostname="localhost";
            var port=9001;
            var client = new Paho.Client(hostname, port, "clientId");
            
            client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
            client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;
            client.connect( {onSuccess:onConnect} );
            
            function onConnect() {
                console.log("onConnect");
                client.subscribe("/World");
                client.subscribe("test");
                var message = new Paho.Message("Hello FROM WS");
                message.destinationName = "test";
                client.send(message);
            };
            
            function sendMessage() {
                var message = new Paho.Message("From Xforms via JS");
                message.destinationName = "test";
                client.send(message);
            }
            
            function onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
            if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0)
                console.log("onConnectionLost:"+responseObject.errorMessage);
            };
            
            function onMessageArrived(message) {
                console.log("onMessageArrived:"+message.payloadString);
                                // Generate an Event for XForms here?
            };
</script>

    <xf:repeat id="r_messages" nodeset="message">
        <xf:output value="."/>
    </xf:repeat>

    <xf:trigger id="t_message">
        <xf:label>BUTTON</xf:label>
        <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
            <xf:insert nodeset="message" at="last()" position="after"/>
            <xf:setvalue ref="message[last()]" value="'button clicked'"/>
        </xf:action>
    </xf:trigger>

    <xf:trigger id="t_send">
        <xf:label>SEND MQTT MESSAGE</xf:label>
        <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
            <xf:load resource="javascript:sendMessage()"/>
        </xf:action>
    </xf:trigger>

<!--
    <xf:action event="????">
        <xf:insert nodeset="message" at="last()" position="after"/>
        <xf:setvalue ref="message[last()]" value="'MQTT MESSAGE RECEIVED'"/>
    <xf:action>
-->

</body>
</html>


OK - got the main parts of this working now, so publishing answer.
Using events to communicate between the Paho library and Xforms.
Reading (not writing yet) Xforms model from with JS to get config.
I'm using XSLTForms specific JS libraries - including the fleur library.
<?xml
    version="1.0"
    encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet
    href="declarative4all/build/xsl/xsltforms.xsl"
    type="text/xsl"?>
<?xsltforms-options
    debug="yes"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:ht="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"   
      xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
      xmlns:mq="http://example.org/mqtt"
      lang="en">
<head>
    <title>MQTT AND XForms</title>
    <meta
        charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

    <script
        type="text/javascript"
        src="js/paho-mqtt.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function dispatch_event(event_str) {
            console.log("Dispatch Event", event_str);
            var model=document.querySelector("#model");
            XsltForms_xmlevents.dispatch(model, event_str);
        }

        function do_connect() {
            var hostname=fleur("instance()/connection/@hostname");
            var port=Number(fleur("instance()/connection/@port"));
            var clientID=fleur("instance()/connection/@clientID");
            client = new Paho.Client(hostname, port, clientID);

            client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
            //client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;
            client.connect( {onSuccess:onConnect} );
        }

        function do_disconnect() {
            client.disconnect();
            dispatch_event("mqtt_connectionlost");
        }

        function onConnect() {
            console.log("onConnect");
            dispatch_event("mqtt_onconnect");
        };

        function onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
            if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
                console.log("onConnectionLost:"+responseObject.errorMessage);
                dispatch_event("mqtt_connectionlost");
            }
        };
            
    </script>

    <xf:model id="model">

    <xf:instance>
        <client xmlns="">

            <connection
                connected="false"
                hostname="localhost"
                port="9001"
                clientID="browser"
            />
            
            <subscriptions>
                <subscription topic="test"/>
            </subscriptions>            
        </client>
    </xf:instance>

    <xf:instance id="testing">
            <data xmlns="">
                <hostname>abc</hostname>
            </data>
    </xf:instance>

    <xf:bind
            ref="connection/@port"
            type="integer"/>
    <xf:bind
            ref="connection/@connected"
            type="boolean"
            readonly="true()"/>


        <xf:action ev:event="xforms-ready"/>

        <xf:action ev:event="mqtt_onconnect">
            <xf:setvalue ref="connection/@connected" value="true()"/>
        </xf:action>

        <xf:action ev:event="mqtt_connectionlost">
            <xf:setvalue ref="connection/@connected" value="false()"/>
        </xf:action>

        <xf:action ev:event="xforms-invalid">
            <xf:message>invalid?</xf:message>
        </xf:action>
    </xf:model>

</head>
<body>
    <h1> MQTT CLIENT TEST </h1>
        <xf:group ref="connection">
            <xf:input ref="@connected">
                <xf:label>CONNECTED?</xf:label>
            </xf:input>
        </xf:group>

            <xf:group ref="instance()/connection[@connected=false()]">
                <xf:label>CONNECTION DETAILS</xf:label>
                    <xf:output value="link"/>
                    <xf:input ref="@hostname">
                        <xf:label>hostname</xf:label>
                    </xf:input>
                    <xf:input ref="@port">
                        <xf:label>port</xf:label>
                    </xf:input>
                    <xf:input ref="@clientID">
                        <xf:label>clientID</xf:label>
                    </xf:input>
                    <xf:trigger id="t_do_connect">
                        <xf:label>CONNECT</xf:label>
                        <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
                            <xf:dispatch targetid="model" name="mqtt_do_connect"/>
                        </xf:action>
                    </xf:trigger>
            </xf:group>

            <xf:group ref="instance()/connection[@connected=true()]">
                    <xf:trigger id="t_do_disconnect">
                        <xf:label>DISCONNECT</xf:label>
                        <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
                            <xf:dispatch targetid="model" name="mqtt_do_disconnect"/>
                        </xf:action>
                    </xf:trigger>
            </xf:group>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.querySelector('#model').addEventListener('mqtt_do_connect', do_connect);
        document.querySelector('#model').addEventListener('mqtt_do_disconnect', do_disconnect);
    </script>


</body>
</html>

Screenshots:


The nice thing about Xforms being declarative is that if you shutdown the MQTT server - the model automatically notices - and in this test implementation - the login form is automatically re-displayed.
